# Parent Child relation on already created SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, parent-child, parent

I have the following table (immutable) on SQL:

| CATEGORY | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| Section | A |
| Division | 01 |
| Group | 011 |
| Class | 0111 |
| Class | 0112 |
| Division | 02 |
| Group | 021 |
| Class | 0211 |

I want to say that CLASSES (ex 0111 & 0112) belongs to GROUP (011) who belongs to DIVISION (01) who belongs to SECTION (A).

Example: If somebody searches Class 0211, I want my table to know that Class belongs to SECTION A.

How can I do this? Thanks guys.

Comment: Well the `code` appears to impart the concept of parenthood, but `Section` does not follow that same logic. Are there more than one Sections

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of sections (A,B,C,D,E,F...) and it not follows any path between Sections and the numbers. Division, Gruop and Class yes, as you know.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by creating a new column who joins "SECTION + all" (Example: C0411), because that relation is impossible to do via programming.

Now, i have all muy fields related by nums (011 belongs to 01...) and Section also related thanks to this new column:

[Example of how many SECTIONS are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Thr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will give you the dependencies between your rows. If you could please post an expected output, I'll be happy to tweak the answer so it meets your requirements.

```
with aux (category, code) as(
    select 'Section',   'A' from dual union all
    select 'Division',  '01' from dual union all
    select 'Group', '011' from dual union all
    select 'Class', '0111' from dual union all
    select 'Class', '0112' from dual union all
    select 'Division',  '02' from dual union all
    select 'Group', '021' from dual union all
    select 'Class', '0211' from dual)
SELECT
    a.*,
    sys_connect_by_path(code, '>') hier
FROM
    aux a
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR decode(category, 'Section', 1, 'Division', 2, 'Group',
                 3, 'Class', 4, 5) = decode(category, 'Section', 1, 'Division', 2, 'Group',
                                            3, 'Class', 4, 5) - 1;
```

Output:

```
Category  Code Hier
--------------------
Section A   >A
Division    01  >A>01
Group   011 >A>01>011
Class   0111    >A>01>011>0111
Class   0112    >A>01>011>0112
Class   0211    >A>01>011>0211
Group   021 >A>01>021
Class   0111    >A>01>021>0111
Class   0112    >A>01>021>0112
Class   0211    >A>01>021>0211
Division    02  >A>02
Group   011 >A>02>011
Class   0111    >A>02>011>0111
Class   0112    >A>02>011>0112
Class   0211    >A>02>011>0211
Group   021 >A>02>021
Class   0111    >A>02>021>0111
Class   0112    >A>02>021>0112
Class   0211    >A>02>021>0211
Division    01  >01
Group   011 >01>011
Class   0111    >01>011>0111
Class   0112    >01>011>0112
Class   0211    >01>011>0211
Group   021 >01>021
Class   0111    >01>021>0111
Class   0112    >01>021>0112
Class   0211    >01>021>0211
Division    02  >02
Group   011 >02>011
Class   0111    >02>011>0111
Class   0112    >02>011>0112
Class   0211    >02>011>0211
Group   021 >02>021
Class   0111    >02>021>0111
Class   0112    >02>021>0112
Class   0211    >02>021>0211
Group   011 >011
Class   0111    >011>0111
Class   0112    >011>0112
Class   0211    >011>0211
Group   021 >021
Class   0111    >021>0111
Class   0112    >021>0112
Class   0211    >021>0211
Class   0111    >0111
Class   0112    >0112
Class   0211    >0211
```

Comment: If you found this helpful, please don't forget to upvote it.